# How to pass a callback function to the $compile service in an angularJS controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am still learning AngularJS.

I have the following function in the JS file I use to load the angular objects:

```
app.controller("myController", ['$scope', '$compile', function ($scope, $compile) {
var $theContainer = $('.container123');
...

this.loadStuff = function () {
                $compile('<layout-withbars></layout-withbars>')($scope, function (clonedElement, $scope) {
                    $theContainer.html(clonedElement); //  **this line is where my tests show a runtime issue **
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('.progress-bar').each(function () {
                           var $bar = $(this);
                           $bar.css('width', $bar.attr('aria-valuenow') + '%');
                            });
                        }, 1500);
                });
        };
}]);
```

The directive itself loads correctly, it contains bootstrap progress bars. The objective of this "loadStuff" function is to load the directive and then make the progress bars change from 0% to X% completion with the default bootstrap transitions.

if I call this block (**block 1**) on the page it triggers the behavior I need:

```
 $('.progress-bar').each(function () {
                           var $bar = $(this);
                           $bar.css('width', $bar.attr('aria-valuenow') + '%');
                            });
```

layout-withbars.html:

```
<div ng-repeat="aProgressbar in progressbars" class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{aProgressbar.complete}}" style="width: 0%;">
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem:

I had to attach a "setTimeout" function around my controller call to **block 1**. I did it because after some testing I believe the $compile service directive injection/processing finishes executing after the described **block 1** is called. I highlighted it on the code above.

Is there a way to organize the execution timing here? my 1.5s delay might not be enough in some cases.

I was looking for a callback function from the $compile service. I believe it to be the "postLink". I tried to implement it but had no luck yet.

What would be the best way to issue **block 1**'s execution after the $compile service directive injection/processing finishes executing?

By the way, I also tried this around **block 1**, without success:

```
$theContainer.html(clonedElement).promise().done(function(){
...
}
```

Comment: What's the reason of using `$compile` in your code? looks like you are expecting to have only single instance of progress bar directive.

Comment: Besides usage of JQuery in Angular app is a sign of bad design or misunderstanding of Angular principles. Just simply switch to data-bound manipulation and you even won't have to "catch" the event of directive being linked

Comment: This is a simplified version of my code... the $compile is used to inject the directive that contains a variable number of progress bars (which FYI, are generated with a ng-repeat in my code).  Because the data itself is static, there is no need to use data binding I would think.

Comment: How would you tackle this idea of issuing a command to be processed after the $compile service finishes its business?

Comment: Is the `ng-repeat` inside the directive? Data-binding is  the way to do things in Angular. Besides `$compile` is not the only thing to be done. That's why you were forced with the timeout. However in real-life the time needed for DOM to be in place is 10 to 50 ms

Comment: I just updated the question's directive template code block with the ng-repeat . Angular actually takes 50-300ms to process the $compile in my tests with the necessary amount of progress bars. Are you suggesting there is no callback function in the $compile service?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85369/discussion-between-the-fabio-and-kirill-slatin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand the reluctance in using the `$compile` service... There are no additional delays imposed by it. In my tests I observed that it makes the browser only load the directive templates when the directive is injected with the `$compile` calls, hence loading is actually faster then using `ng-if`.

Anyway, Kirill Slatin' answer pointed me on the right direction:

In order to execute functions on DOM elements generated by angular directives the directive definition provides callback functions for *before* and *after* angular's "directive compiling". I got it from [Angular's documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#comprehensive-directive-api).

The solution here was to refactor **block 1** into the directive's `link` attribute within the `postLink` and `preLink` functions. After that no more execution time issues happen:

```
app.directive('layoutWithbars', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'layout-withbars.html',
             link: {
                pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                   for (var i=0; i< scope.progressBars.length; i++)
                      scope.progressBars[i].range = 0;
                },
                post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                   $timeout(function () {
                   for (var i=0; i< scope.progressBars.length; i++)
                      scope.progressBars[i].range = scope.progressBars[i].complete;
                }, 100);

            }
        }
        };
    });
```

and the directive body would have the following data-binding so it would be more angularJS like:

```
<div class="progress" ng-repeat="aProgressBar in progressBars">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" 
      aria-valuenow="{{aProgressBar.complete}}" 
      aria-valuemin="0" 
      aria-valuemax="100" 
      ng-style="{width: aProgressBar.range +'%'}">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes I insist on removing pointless Jquery code and mis-usage of `$compile`. And thus no callback functions with timeouts are required.

Instead of manually telling angular to compile the directive it's possible to let it appear in the DOM via `ng-if`. This fits well a scenario when there is a limited number of directives (one in your case) to be dynamically added or removed from DOM.

```
<layout-withbars ng-if="showProgress"></layout-withbars>
```

So `loadStuff` should only set `$scope.showProgress = true;`
Keep in mind that `ng-if` in contrary to `ng-show` actually removes the element when expression is `falsy`. Thus each time it becomes `truthy` and element is added to DOM the directive will be linked once again. Concluding in `link` (or actually `postLink`) handler of the directive to be exactly the same handler you were trying to achieve in `setTimeout()`. However this won't be required any longer since there is a directive that allows to databind element's style.

```
<div class="progress-bar" 
     role="progressbar" 
     ng-style="{width: aProgressbar.complete + '%';">
```

This way the width will be updated as soon as data in model is updated.

[Sample plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/h7NaWaMkzss5mDXjrGP5?p=preview)

Comment: There is one thing missing though. The data behind "aProgressbar.complete" does not change, it is static report data. I am using the progress bar because it has nice css transitional movement when the width attribute changes. The idea was to load the progress bars with 0% width and after finishing loading the DOM content modify the width to the value of "aProgressbar.complete" so the css transition is applied.

Comment: Thank you for showing an alternative to the use of $compile. I really appreciate the effort. I have just found the way to implement a callback function for the $compile service. I will describe it with an answer in a minute.

Comment: Did you mean animation like in [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/h7NaWaMkzss5mDXjrGP5?p=preview)?

Comment: But this does not answer the question.